# Vuetify Color picker @input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, color-picker

I am using the [Vuetify color picker](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/color-pickers/) to change the background and text colors of my elements. Currently, I am storing the hex color values in Firestore. Using `@input="updateColor"` as an attribute on the `v-color-picker` I am calling the function to store the value in Firestore.

The problem is that `@input` gets called every time the mouse is moved when selecting a color. Because of this, my code is making a lot of update calls to Firestore.
For example, when sliding from white to black in the color picker it makes around 100 calls to the function.

This is my code:

> v-color-picker HTML:

```js
<v-color-picker
    dot-size="25"
    mode="hexa"
    v-model="background.color"
    @input="updateColor"
></v-color-picker>
```

> updateColor function:

```js
const updateColor = () => {
    const data = {
        backgroundColor: background.value.color,
        textColor: text.value.color
    }

    console.log("Update");

    // Storing the data in firestore
    currentPage.updateComponent(props.component.uid, data)
    .catch((error) => {
        app.setError(error)
    });
}
```

When looking at the [v-color-picker-api](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-color-picker/#events) there are 3 events (input, update:color, update:mode). I have tried the `@update:color` event but it produces the same result. And `@update:mode` is not used for selecting colors.

*Ideally I do not want to use a button to apply the color.*

I am using Vue 2 with the composition API.
How can I make fewer calls to Firestore?

This is a snippet showing how many function calls are made:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    amountOfCalls: 0
  },
  methods: {
    updateColor: function() {
      this.amountOfCalls++;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <div class="d-flex">
      <v-color-picker size="25" mode="hexa" @input="updateColor"></v-color-picker>

      <p>Amount of function calls made: <b>{{ amountOfCalls }}</b></p>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to add an APPLY button - upon clicking on it you will store the `v-model` of the color picker into Firebase. Or even better - put a button named PICK COLOR in the place of the color picker, this button will open a dialog with the color picker and buttons APPLY and CANCEL. Then you can store the value in Firebase upon clicking on that APPLY button.

Comment: That is a good solution. Its just not really what I want.

Comment: Then you can use a watcher and `debounce` from `lodash` to update Firebase only if the color has not been changed for at least 0.5 seconds.